# Ordering fields in .NET web service response

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm calling a .NET web service (WCF I think, I'm not a .NET expert) from mobile apps to get a JSON response, and I would like to reorder the fields.  Yes, I know the specification of JSON (to the extent there is such a thing) says it doesn't support ordering.  I'm just trying to find a way to order the response string from the web service before I resort to updating the client apps to sort the data afterwards.

I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx

but using `[DataMember(Order = 0)]` on each field (with different sort values of course) has no effect on the order of the fields in the response.  Is this attribute only for XML responses?

Comment: I'm curious what kind of brittle, un-updatable solution has been developed that depends on the order of JSON properties. I mean, if it's being parsed into an object, then there is not even any meaning behind the word "order". Does the solution work directly with the JSON string?

Comment: So you want to modify the output from the service without updating neither the service or the client app? Where do you want to put your code?

Comment: No, I want to modify the service, but not the client apps.

Comment: One of the apps using the data unfortunately spits the data into a CSV file without any consideration of field ordering.  Now we need to fix it, and are hoping to do so without an app update.

Comment: @nasch - Unless the app is grabbing the JSON string literal and then manually parsing it (i.e. **not** converting to a JavaScript object first), then the order of the properties from the server will have exactly zero effect on the order of the CSV fields.

Comment: JSON is just text, you can output your values as text in any order you want. You will have to write your own JSON exporter of course

Comment: @Hogan - Unless you are using a serializer to output the JSON for you, in which case you are at the mercy of the library.

Comment: @JDB - I'm suggesting not using the library... then there is **NO MERCY** :)

Comment: @nasch `[DataMember(Order = index)]` **should** work, are you actually checking the output JSON for the ordering?

Comment: The apps are not javascript based, so are not turning the JSON string into a javascript object. The problem app is iOS and I'm not an iOS developer, but if it would help to have details of what it's doing with the JSON I can get them.  I don't think it's worth writing my own exporter.  And yes, I have checked the output from the client, and the fields are in alphabetical order rather than how I've ordered them.

Comment: @nasch - Even if you are using Swift or some other language, the key question is whether the app is even paying attention to the order of the properties. If there is any kind of de-serialization going on, then you are wasting your efforts to re-order them in the server response. An alphabetical listing of properties is how just about all reflection libraries work. I've never seen an app manually process a JSON string before, which is why I ask. I highly recommend that you check the app logic before you waste any more time on this problem

Comment: @nasch but have you checked the actual response, or what the client says it's the response? The client may be deserializing the result and output it alphabetically ordered (even if the service is ordering it differently), that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Jcl No, I'm just checking the response string directly.

Comment: @JDB, I think I know what you're saying, and I'm consulting with the iOS developer.

Comment: This is an app/client consideration for sure.. if you want to provide some sort of field ordering schema, that's fine.. but the app/client are still going to need to account for it..

Comment: @JDB I think your comment was the key.  We've determined there is no viable solution without updating the client apps.  If you would like to rephrase as an answer I'll accept it, and thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your JSON properties typically doesn't matter because the JSON is almost always de-serialized into an object. Once that happens, the original "order" of the properties becomes totally meaningless.

For example, consider the following code:

```js
const data = JSON.parse('{ "a": "Aquaman", "b": "Batman", "c": "Catwoman" }');
// data.a == "Aquaman"
// data.b == "Batman"
// data.c == "Catwoman"
```

Changing the order of these properties would have no effect on the de-serialized object. Most object-oriented languages, including JavaScript, Java and C#, have no built-in concept of property "order".

```js
const data = JSON.parse('{ "c": "Catwoman", "b": "Batman", "a": "Aquaman" }');
// data.a == "Aquaman"
// data.b == "Batman"
// data.c == "Catwoman"
```

If your client application is de-serializing the JSON before it outputs the CSV file, then the order of the JSON properties will have no effect on the order of the CSV fields.

Changing the order of the CSV fields is going to require updating the app.

You *could* write your own JSON serializer to ensure the order of the properties is as desired and then write your own JSON parser to convert the JSON string directly to CSV, thus preserving the order of those fields. De-serializing the JSON to an object will destroy field order information, so you'd have to go straight from original JSON string to CSV.

Or you could change the format of your JSON to make use of arrays, etc, which do preserve element order. Something like:

```
const data = JSON.parse('{ "c": "Catwoman", "b": "Batman", "a": "Aquaman", "__fieldMeta": { "order": [ "c", "b", "a" ] } }');
// data.__fieldMeta.order[0] == "c"
// data.__fieldMeta.order[1] == "b"
// data.__fieldMeta.order[2] == "a"
```

Or you could switch to a serialization format that does preserve element order, like XML.

```xml
<data c="Catwoman" b="Batman" a="Aquaman" />
```

```js
const dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
  `<data c="Catwoman" b="Batman" a="Aquaman" />`, "application/xml");
// dom.firstElementChild.attributes[0].localName == "c"
// dom.firstElementChild.attributes[1].localName == "b"
// dom.firstElementChild.attributes[2].localName == "a"
```

Unfortunately, all of these options will require updating the client application. I don't think there's going to be a way to work around that.